# Java Docker - No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:

Tags: java, docker, jdbc

В своем файле `File.java` я работаю c базой данных. Что бы с ней работать нужен `driver.jar`.

Когда я запускаю свой проект через `NetBeans`, я должен был добавить `driver.jar` рядом с файлами, и тогда все работает.

Что бы скомпилировать проект через `cmd` окно я добавил `driver.jar` в переменную системы `classpath` и тогда тоже все заработало.

Но сейчас я запускаю этот файл через `Docker` с помощью файла `Dockerfile`.
Содержимое `Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM openjdk:latest

WORKDIR /java

COPY . /java

RUN javac File.java

CMD ["java", "File"]
```

И так как я в строчке `COPY . /java` копирую все содержимое с папки с файлом `Dockerfile` в определенную папку на сервере, то было бы логично ище и рядом с `File.java` поместить `driver.jar` - что я и сделал.

Но почему то я и дальше получаю ошибку о том что он не найден.

Возможно нужно его добавить как то в переменную среды в докере? Или как это исправить?

Comment: `CMD ["java", "-cp", ".;driver.jar", "File"]`

Comment: Но на самом деле, конечно, лучше использовать какой-нибудь Maven + Spring Boot, который будет делать тебе jar файл, в котором упакованы все твои классы и все зависимости.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html#standard-options-for-java

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, почему после изменения `CMD ["java", "File"]` на `CMD ["java", "-cp", ".;driver.jar", "File"]` я получаю ошибку `Error: Could not find or load main class File
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: File`?

Comment: В докере линукс, там разделитель в classpath не точка с запятой, а двоеточие